# ActionBarActivity crashes my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I am trying to extend an ActionBarActivity. But it crashes my app each time. I know this question has been asked a lot. But solutions I found on the internet are not working. I did not import the **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar** file as I have imported the library project **android-support-v7-appcompat**.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.actionbartry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actionbartry"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
<color name="mycolor">#E4E4E4</color>
</resources>
```

Log:

```
12-04 00:34:59.314: I/art(2009): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity>
12-04 00:34:59.316: I/art(2009): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity>
12-04 00:34:59.325: I/art(2009): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.actionbartry.MainActivity>
12-04 00:34:59.328: D/AndroidRuntime(2009): Shutting down VM
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009): Process: com.example.actionbartry, PID: 2009
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.actionbartry/com.example.actionbartry.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.actionbartry.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.actionbartry-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.actionbartry.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.actionbartry-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     ... 10 more
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.actionbartry.MainActivity
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         ... 14 more
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.actionbartry.MainActivity
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):         ... 13 more
12-04 00:34:59.401: E/AndroidRuntime(2009):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
12-04 00:38:51.281: I/Process(2009): Sending signal. PID: 2009 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what it says in logs, please show your log  !

Comment: need logcat output..

Comment: It doesn't resolve your issue, but **use Android Studio**, use the **AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity**, use a **AppCompatTheme**.

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity